# Hovered border makes words look like they are shaking

Tags: html, css, border

I have a popup window that displays navigation links. Whenever the user hovers over the link I have a white border display around it. My issue is, the `1px` from the border is causing the navigation links to look like they are slightly shaking. What can I do to make the navigation links stay fixed and not move at all?

To see this in the snippet, click on the second image and the popup will appear. 
Then simply hover over the text.

```js
$('.nav-popup').hide();

$("#nav-btn").on("click", function (event) {
 $('.nav-popup').fadeIn(350);
});

  //----- CLOSE
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

```css
.nav-popup {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 color: #FFF;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
}
.popup-close {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 right: 50px;
}
#x-close {
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transition: transform .4s ease;
}
#x-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
}
.nav-popup-inner {
 position: relative;
 height: 100%;
}
#nav-list {
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
}
.nav-item {
 display: block;
 margin: 50px 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2.5em;
}
.nav-item a {
 color: #FFF;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 0.2s ease;
}
.nav-item a:hover {
 color: #BFBFBF;
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 padding: 15px;
 border-radius: 7px;
 transition: 0.2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="nav-down">
 <div id="logo">
  <img src="/images/eslich.png" alt="">
 </div>
 <a href="#0" id="nav-btn"><img src="/icons/mobile_menu_white.png" style="height: 28px; width: 28px;" alt="Website Design Services Mobile Menu Button"></a>
 <div class="nav-popup" data-popup="popup-1">
  <div class="nav-popup-inner">
   <ul id="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">SAFETY</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
   </ul>
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#"><img src="/icons/delete-cross.png" alt="" height="40px" width="40px" id="x-close"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I don't think I get it. I can't see any "shaking" links at all. Maybe a crossbrowser issue?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out. I added a transparent border to the normal state. This did the trick.

Comment: You could go with a solid outline `outline: 1px solid #fff; ` rather than a border and bypass the need to have the border to begin with. Or if you need the content to have a border inside use something along the lines of `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this is due to `webkit` `translate` option. Since you're translating at `-50%`, every time you `hover` on it, your element will lose its `height` reference and reposition, causing the "shaking" effect.

Since you're using this hack to vertically align, I'd recommend following one of these two methods: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LvmLjexc/1/